Exception in Execute Select java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread is already started
Getting Excpetion in Execute Select java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread is already started when we are trying to execute a select statement in a sql server through java below is the code snippet
QueryExecuter queryExec = null; 
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
queryExec = new QueryExecuter("Sql");   //To get connection from MS SQL Server
ps = queryExec.getPreparedStatement(RegistrationSqlCatalog.strGetCartItemVinData);
ps.setString(1,rdto.getVIN());
rs = queryExec.executeSelect(ps);

the thing is we are not using any thread to start this process at all we are connecting that database using jdbc connections and in the logs we can see the below lines
SQL Data source iscom.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@4a4adf7d
QueryExecuter.PreparedStatement() sqlQuery   SELECT CARTID FROM CARTITEMS WHERE UPPER(VINNUMBER) = ?
Excpetion in Execute Select java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread is already started

and we are using some old stack where the data sources and all are managed in WebSphere admin console.
The same build is working fine in DEV environment and surprisingly it is not working in TEST environment where the same jar(mssql-jdbc-10.2.0.jre8.jar) file is used and also the same ear is used for deployment.
So we tried connecting the TEST Db into our DEV environment it is working fine even then, but the same Db in TEST environment not working.
We checked with jar, ear and websphere version or even java version they are looking good, apart from these will there be any factors effecting this process, if so let us know.
public QueryExecuter (String sql) throws SQLException, NamingException{
        con = this.getSQLConnection();
    }

private Connection getSQLConnection() throws SQLException, NamingException{
        DataSource datasrc = null;
        datasrc = OntracServiceLocator.getInstance().getSQLDataSource();
        con = datasrc.getConnection();
        if (con == null) cat.info("Query Executer Unable to get Connection ");
        return con;
    }

public DataSource getSQLDataSource() throws NamingException {
        String dsName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/sql";
        cat.info("data source " + dsName);
        ic = getInitialContext();
        DataSource ds = null;
        ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup(dsName);
        cat.info("SQL Data source is" + ds);
        return ds;
    }

above the code chain for QueryExecuter
Can anyone help us with this issue?

Please put the whole error stacktrace here, not just the highlights. Also, what's QueryExecuter

Please put it in the question, not comments

You are not showing the key QueryExecuter.PreparedStatement() method here.
Whats the point of that QueryExecuter in the first place? It doesnt bring any value.

@Gas it is there in the first code snippet itself
and that query executer is only getting the sql connection
